# react-beautiful-dnd inconsistent drop zone width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1oprpkq8xj) I forked official example from git. I only changed drop zone with to 500px.

The problem is if I grab the beginning of the box, then only a bit more than half of the drop zone is active. [image]

Same thing happens if I grab the end of the box, then the half left side is inactive.  [image]

But if I grab the middle of the box, the whole box seems to be active.

Is this a bug? Or I missing something from configuration? Maybe CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dragging with a mouse the impact of an item is based on it's center position. So the center position of an item needs to be over the list for it to be the drop target

Comment: Bonus: if you don’t want a dead zone between the lists then have them set next to each other. Margin between them is fine

Comment: Is there a way to make the whole drop zone available when grabbing not on box center, but one of the side? Also just noticed, if I grab box from left list on box's very right side and move it to left side of the right list, the left list is still a drop zone. even though mouse is already in right list.

Comment: The mouse grab position is not considered. Only the items center of mass

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct - because it is :)